# How to get the intersections lat/lng on overpass api?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I've already knew that I can find all intersections on map by
[Code](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/jzC).

My question is that I've knew one intersection and how I can get the information like lat and lon on others connecting intersections .

I've already get lat and lon of intersection A .
How to get the information on others connecting intersections in the following picture?

[image: Example.]

Comment: BTW: Your query is not suitable to find intersections for arbitrary locations, see this example http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/jA0 - one street may be broken into multiple OSM ways, and intersections of those OSM ways is what your query returns. Unfortunately, there's no other way of doing it. You just need to be aware of it, that the query has some shortcomings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with your current query since it only returns *nodes*. To determine other connected intersections you will need *nodes* and *ways*.

Downloading ways with the [highway key](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway) and all of their nodes can be done with a really simple query:

```
way[highway];
(._;>;);
out;
```

See the [example](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/jzF) at overpass turbo.

Afterwards you have to compute a routing graph. There is a step-by-step explanation for [building a routing graph from OSM data](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/19213/how-can-i-convert-an-osm-xml-file-into-a-graph-representation/19214). For a general overview take a look at [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) in the OSM wiki.